# using Rails to_prepare event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, initializer

I'm trying to get the to_prepare event to work on a new Rails 3.2.1 project. I've placed the  following:

```
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  puts 'here i am before a request'
end
```

into an initializer under config/initializers. According to the documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initialization-events), this block should run on every request to the app when running in development mode, and only once in production. I'm working in development mode, and this block does not run on every request, instead it runs only when I boot up the application, and never again.

The following is a sample of output from when I load the app.

```
   rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
here i am before a request
[2012-03-02 20:29:46] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-03-02 20:29:46] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
[2012-03-02 20:29:46] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=37897 port=3000
```

When I make subsequent requests, the string 'here i am...' is not displayed, only the regular output from the Rails log. All my searching has only mentioned documentation that seems to tell me to do things this way. Is there anything I might be missing?

Comment: Did you turn on `config.cache_classes`?

Answer (score 8):

to_prepare is called every time your project is reloaded, which since Rails 3.2 means every time you change a file.

refs: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7152#issuecomment-8397470